# Website building, ask server to run a script with input

Tags: javascript, python, request, web, send

I'm quite a newbie in everything related to web development, but I had this project in my mind that I really wanted to realize.

At the moment I am struggling with a method to send a request to the server hosting the website. The idea is that from the site you can enter keywords, and those keywords should be run in a script (python or java(script)) on the server after which it returns an output to the webpage. In theory this script could be executed in the website itself as javascript, but I would like to use the computing power and internet access from the server.

I have researched on using Json and javascript for the job, but I think there has to be a better way for this purpose. Is there anyone that can direct me where to look?

Comment: python OR javascript! You can definetly do it in both languages, you decide which you like more. Then also have a look at the term `AJAX` and get a good tutorial for one of the languages and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build your form in HTML. (More info: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

In client-side JavaScript (the code that website users have executing in their browser), you should use the jQuery library to scoop the data out of your form.  Take a look at the [`.submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) and [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) functions to get started.  Then you can use jQuery's [AJAX function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to submit requests to the server-side API in a JSON format.

On the server, in addition to creating a way of serving up the webpages (with their client-side JavaScript), you will then need to create an API to receive and respond to these requests.  One way to do this is by running Node.js with Express, which will allow you to write your API in JavaScript.  The downside to this is you will have to pay to get a full-fledged virtualized cloud server through AWS, Rackspace, or another host.  The other option is for you to write your API in PHP, which is supported by free webhosts like [x10hosting.com](http://x10hosting.com/).